In an Azure App Service, how do I allow DefaultAzureCredential to get bearer token from App Registration (Enterprise Application)?
I have an App Registration in Entra with permissions granted to call another App Registration from same Entra. When I use client secret to get a bearer token via http for grant_type=client_credentials - the token works fine.
Now I want to use DefaultAzureCredential inside an Azure App Service to get the same token without client secret. When I use DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync - I get a token with no Roles and oid set to the system-assigned identity of my App Service. I tried Passing DefaultAzureCredentialOptions.ManagedIdentityClientId set to Client Id of my App Registration, but then I get code 400, indicating that my App Service does not have permissions to use the identity from App Registration.
Am I missing some configuration to link my App Service to my App Registration?
Update I've recreated the setup, here is what it looks like:
App Registrations:

Http call gets me the token with roles:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/62765715-2081-4050-bdc7-8c2e178d7424/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/2.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=1009eb01-33c0-4bf9-ad54-726d50fb18b5
&client_secret=zlr8*************************************
&scope=api:%2F%2F442b3378-34c6-421f-8912-d3f18a004d1c%2F.default

{
  "aud": "api://442b3378-34c6-421f-8912-d3f18a004d1c",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/62765715-2081-4050-bdc7-8c2e178d7424/",
  "iat": 1735085790,
  "nbf": 1735085790,
  "exp": 1735089690,
  "aio": "k2BgYDh97Ul1oVFTEfumuQ1zVuQdBQA=",
  "appid": "1009eb01-33c0-4bf9-ad54-726d50fb18b5",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/62765715-2081-4050-bdc7-8c2e178d7424/",
  "oid": "d5760fed-eaf1-4e6e-aed2-a2b65ac0a030",
  "rh": "1.AREAFVd2YoEgUEC9x4wuF410JHgzK0TGNB9CiRLT8YoATRwXAQARAA.",
  "roles": [
    "Vehicles.Read",
    "Vehicles.Write"
  ],
  "sub": "d5760fed-eaf1-4e6e-aed2-a2b65ac0a030",
  "tid": "62765715-2081-4050-bdc7-8c2e178d7424",
  "uti": "4gbiMCOLlk2bJqHrffsaAA",
  "ver": "1.0"
}

Is there any way in Azure to give it access to the above token (or similar, as long as the audience and roles are there) without using client secret? Preferably via DefaultAzureCredential?
Update2:
I have tried the following

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `
    -ObjectId e67aa4a7-e487-47b9-8d27-78cf30888f61 `
    -PrincipalId e67aa4a7-e487-47b9-8d27-78cf30888f61 `
    -Id f39a570e-6309-496f-b81a-0de5a9e07e2e `
    -ResourceId 3d73b9d4-b4b6-4741-b1f6-22a7fa6453d2

Output:
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment: Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Permission being assigned was not found on application
RequestId: 8cf83ecf-c707-4621-adfe-52397837d690
DateTimeStamp: Fri, 27 Dec 2024 21:10:58 GMT
Details: PropertyName  - None, PropertyErrorCode  - InvalidUpdate
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed


“get the same token without client secret” Can you elaborate on what it is you’re trying to do? I’m not sure what you’re describing here is necessarily possible.

Further, authentication using client credentials isn’t supported via DefaultAzureCredential according to the docs - can you link to the source upon which you’re basing your implicit claim to the contrary?

“code 400, indicating that my App Service does not have permissions to use the identity from App Registration.” An HTTP status code 400 doesn’t usually indicate anything about authorization. How did you reach this conclusion?

To make use of identity, you need to pass client ID as managed identity and you have to assign API permissions to managed identity and generate token

You cannot use  Client Id of App Registration as DefaultAzureCredentialOptions.ManagedIdentityClientId

Can you brief your exact requirement and paste the code too you are using and scope

@Rukmini I've recreated  the setup and updated the post.

Did you check the below answer to use managed identity to generate the token?

@Rukmini I've tried running the command that you suggested, but i'm getting "Permission being assigned was not found on application". I've updated initial post with screenshot of all resources participating in that command.


Note that: To call another Microsoft Entra Application and generate access token using system managed identity you need to assign the permissions to the managed identity.

Assuming you want to generate token using managed identity in web app service and include roles in it.
I created a Microsoft Entra ID application and created app role:

Assign this app role to system managed identity:

Connect-AzureAD

New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId MIObjectID -Id AppRoleID -PrincipalId MIObjectID -ResourceId MicrosoftEntraServicrPrincipalObjID

You can also make use of latest Microsoft Graph PowerShell module.

When you check the managed identity in the Enterprise application blade, app role is assigned:

Now I used the below code to generate access token using Azure web app system identity:
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class TokenService
    {
        public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            string resource = "api://ClientIDOfEntra/"; 

            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

            var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { resource });

            AccessToken token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);
            Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token.Token}");

            return token.Token;
        }
    }
}

When published to App service access token generated successfully:

Decode the token app roles are displayed:

The appid claim includes the Application ID of system managed identity.
By using the above token, you can call the other application successfully and make sure to use the same scope you are using of client credential flow.
